# How do I allocate memory within this function?

Tags: c++, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have the following function and a hierarchy of classes such that Multinumber is inherited by Pairs, Rational, and Complex. All of these share functions which are virtual in Multinumber. My problem is the following code. The way it is written right now, the newElement variable goes out of scope when it is added to my `setArray` which is of type `Multinumber**`, and I need to figure out some way to allocate memory within this function. Oddly, paramters that are passed into the function, even when printed on the first line, are always empty when I do a `cout<<newElement->tostring();` Can anyone tell me what is wrong here?

```
bool Set::addElement(Multinumber* newElement)
{
    bool success = false;
    if(isFull())
    {
        resize();
    }
    if(!isMember(newElement))
    {
        setArray[numElements] = newElement;
        numElements++;
        success = true;
    }
    return success;
}
```

EDIT: Yes the poster is correct, this is a homework assignment

Comment: We need more code. Please post the entire `Set` class. It'd also be handy to see the implementation of `Multinumber`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the real world (I understand from [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351817/how-do-i-dynamically-allocate-memory-to-a-polymorphic-data-type) that this is for homework), you wouldn't implement your own set. The standard library provides this functionality (`std::set` if you want to keep the elements in order; `std::unordered_set` if you're using C++0x and/or have the appropriate extensions, and prioritize speed over the additional functionality).

You should probably also look into some smart-pointer classes.

That said:

In your code, `newElement` isn't going out of scope. What happens is that you've been given a pointer to the calling code's data, and the calling code is then letting the pointed-at thing go out of scope.

[As I responded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351817/how-do-i-dynamically-allocate-memory-to-a-polymorphic-data-type/4351900#4351900) to your previous question, you need to use the "[virtual clone](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/virtual-functions.html#faq-20.8) idiom" to make the copy.

Basically, you want to call `new` with whatever the type is of the passed-in, pointed-at thing, in such a way that a copy is made. To ensure "that a copy is made", the natural thing to do would be to use the copy constructor with `new`, that is `new whatever(my_existing_whatever_instance)`. But in C++, constructors cannot be `virtual`, so we can't actually put the desired type into a `new` call. Instead, we have to fake it with a member function. Since member functions **can** be `virtual`, the correct version `clone` is looked up in the actual pointed-at thing, which is implemented to call `new` using its own type, and calling its own copy constructor. The link provides details.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid memory troubles replace `Multinumber** setArray` with `std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<Multinumber>> setArray`.

Answer (score 0):

If you need it to grow, make it of type `vector<Multinumber*>` and use setArray.push_back(newElement).

You need to make sure that the caller keeps the element alive as long as the vector is alive.  If not, perhaps add a virtual Clone method to Multinumber that returns a copy (and subclasses implement it).  Then, `push_back(newElement->Clone())`.

Comment: I assume he wants a set rather than a vector, i.e. is enforcing the invariant that there can only be one of each value. I further assume, based on previous questions, that he is being required to implement the container for homework.